# Cannot modify managed object: state=released: newValue='false', oldValue='true'

Tags: custom-field, salesforcedx, custom-metadata

has anyone encountered and solved a `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy` error about changing a field from released to non-released? I'm getting this error when deploying to the packaging org.

We've been working with DX in our managed package for like 7 months now, and now suddenly we've received the following error when trying to upload to the packaging org:

> Error  mdapi_output_dir/objects/Donation_App_Setting__mdt.object 
>   Donation_App_Setting__mdt.Technical_User__c  Cannot modify managed
>   object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00NC0000006OYPn,
>   field=IsCaseSensitive, state=released: newValue='false',
>   oldValue='true'

We haven't changed anything in this metadata field since we started working with dx, so I'm lost on what could've happened here and how can I fix it.

I'm 100% sure we haven't changed anything to this field, here is the entire history of the field, which is just the initial commit

[image: Technical_User__c commit history]

Comment: How do you go from SFDX source to MDAPI-ready metadatas ? Can you share the content of the related metadata field XML ? You can not "un-release" an already released field, but if you didn't make any change to provoke that, I agree that is really strange ... ( and makes me afraid for our own managed package ^^ )

Comment: Hi @NicolasVuillamy, I always convert it `sfdx force:source:convert --outputdir mdapi_output_dir --packagename Namespace` and deploy it `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --deploydir mdapi_output_dir -u mydevorg` (haven't get around to test the new `force:source:deploy` command)

Comment: We don't use --packagename on our project (convert then filter results using sfdx-essentials plugin) , but in your case maybe it connects to the packaging org to fetch the content of the package... if you go in the package definition in the org, do you see your field Techniczl_User__c selected ?

Comment: Hi @NicolasVuillamy, the field is in the package definition since version 3.48 (we are on 5.31) and when I convert the source to metadata format in the `package.xml` that gets generated the field is also listed under `<types><name>CustomField</name<members>Donation_App_Setting__mdt.Technical_User__c</members></types>`

Comment: I have the exact same issue using the ant migration tool. It's picked 2 random fields from around 50 custom objects, the rest apparently ok. I have tried re-uploading a set of source which uploaded fine about a week ago, same issue.

Comment: An update - I have resolved my issue by adding `<caseSensitive>true</caseSensitive>` to the relevant fields in the broken objects, and the package build org is now accepting the source again.

Comment: I'm glad you found a workaround @FatalFlaw, unfortunately I can't edit a metadata field after packaged any my field is an `email` field

Comment: @Jose, I understand our situations are different, but just in case it's relevant: one of my fields was an email and one a string (containing something that looks like an email). Best of luck to you.